# Proving inexistence of a PCOMPLETE language in log logarithmic space cannot exist

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, computability, space-complexity

Hello and thank you for helping me understand the following:

I am trying to understand why the following cannot exist: A P-Complete language in regards to a log-logarithmic space.

context: Defining a new kind of reduction: a reduction in log-logarithmic space. For this purpose, we define a log-logarithmic transformer that is identical to a logarithmic transformer, but its working tape can hold $O(log(logn) $symbols and not $O(logn)$ symbols.

We'll say a language A can be reduced in a log-logarithmic space to language B and denote $A ≤_{LL}B$, if exists a transformer with log-logarithmic space that applies a mapping reduction between A to B.

Now, Language C will be called P-complete in regards to reduction in log-logarithmic space if:

1. C belongs to class P
2. For every language A in P exists a reduction in log-logarithmic space to C(meaning $A ≤_{LL} C$).

I am quite lost and all of the hierarchies involved and I cannot understand why this P-complete language cannot exist in log-logarithmic space. Would be very glad if you could help me understand it and elaborate so it will be clear.

Thank you very much for your much appreciated help.